# creating Frame function python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to write a function that creates a frame
This is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

def button(master, txt, line, col):
    new = Button(master, text=txt)
    new.grid(row=line, column =col, columnspan=2)

def frame(nb, txt):
    f = Frame(nb)
    nb.add(f, text = txt)

root = Tk()
nb = Notebook(root)
f1 = frame(nb, '1')
f2 = frame(nb, '2')

button(f1, '1', 0, 0)
nb.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

but when I run the code the button isn't under f1, it's in the master window itself (see picture):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dqjm.png

How can I make it move to be under f1 and when I'm on it I see the Button, and when I'm on f2 there's nothing in the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `frame` function is returning `None` (by virtue of it not explicitly returning anything at all), so the parent/master of the button defaults to the root window.

To fix it, have your function return the frame:

```
def frame(nb, txt):
    ...
    return f
```